Why is Excel not counting time with COUNTIF?
I have a table like the following:



A
B
C




123
24/05/2024  09:42:54



123
24/05/2024  09:42:55
00:00:01


123
24/05/2024  09:42:56
00:00:01


123
24/05/2024  09:42:57
00:00:01



Where C is like =b2-b1. The sheet has over 100,000 rows.
What I want to do is count all the entries in C where the value is 00:00:01, but when I try COUNTIF(c1:c200000, "00:00:01") or COUNTIF(c1:c200000, TIMEVALUE("00:00:01")) or COUNTIF(c1:c200000, TIME(0,0,1)) I get 0.00, when I can easily see the value must be greater than one.
How should I be counting the time difference?
If it's important I'm using Excel for Microsoft 365.

I changed the calculation in column C from =b2-b1 to =SECOND(b2-b1) and changed the COUNTIF to =COUNTIF(c2:c200000, 1), which showed me a value I found more plausible.

Correct! Your original approaches all suffer from a rounding error: the value in C is actually 0,00001157408 but TIMEVALUE("00:00:01") is 0,00001157407. Good enough for most purposes, but comparing two floating point values with = is always tricky. Best to include a rounding function (like SECOND())

@Paul I see! That's good to know. I was hoping C would be some kind of datetime value rather than a number. Today I learned!

Datetime is just a formatting of a number. You can format both, B and C to a number and figure out what that number is.

The way time is represented in excel is that days 1 and time increments smaller than a day is a fraction of a day, e.g., 0.25 is 6 hours. One of the ways I've found to deal with this is to use countif or Countifs like so: =countifs(C:C, ">="&A1, C:C, "<"&A2) where column A is a list of time increments (in order) that I want to count by.

A trick for more precision would be to convert the difference into seconds,
i.e. =(A1-INT(A1)*86400
Dates in spreadsheets are an integer count of days from a base date, with the time of date stored as an additional fraction part.
One day consist of 24x60x60 seconds (= 86400).
So entering =1/86400 in a cell and then formatting it as HH:MM:SS will display the value as 00:00:01.
Further: Adding up a sum of seconds (any number of them) and then dividing it by 86400, will allow to display it as a "days and HH:mm:SS" time by entering
=INT(A1) & " days  " & TEXT(A1-INT(A1)," HH:MM:SS")
in a cell.

Nice. And good grief — of all the dumb ways we programmers have come up with to represent time, a floating point fraction of a day has got to be one of the dumbest.

Another method would be to round the results of your calculation in Column C to the nearest second:
=MROUND(B2-B1,TIME(0,0,1))


Thinking laterally, if every cell in C is either 0 or 1 second, then instead of counting the 1s, why not just use SUM(C)?
